# flagging a question that is taking lots of "thanks" comments

Tags: support

I know that questions taking comments as "thanks" and "me too" should be "protected" from that, right?

Well how do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, if you think something is attracting too many inappropriate posts we can "protect" it.

Just flag it (use the "Other" option) and let us know what you think.

Comment: the "other" option. mmm. ...okay thanks :D LOL "thanks" XD

Comment: And this is why we love you Oli... you beat the metabot to an answer like a boss.

Comment: @hbdgaf - which metabot :D

Comment: @Wilf There's an RSS bot in the chat room that posts new meta questions.